# Limited access to a user's Google Calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to retrieve a Google User's Calendar information in a restricted manner and it seems to me that Google's APIs don't really allow that.

Right now, if I ask the user to give me access to their calendar, I can see all their event names, descriptions, times, etc. I just want to be able to see blocks of times of them being 'busy' instead of the actual event details.

I can't ask my users to share all their information with me, it's pretty absurd. Any way around retrieving a restricted Google Calendar so I can see when they are busy and when they are not?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing) of Calendar API, that you can grant your customers the right to only see when you are free or busy, but not the details of the events. So meaning if your user share the calendar to you, you can able to determine if they are busy or not.

With the help of [`Freebusy: query`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query), you can check here the time your customer is busy or have an event that time.

Take note that `Freebusy.query` supports `timeMin` and `timeMax` values. Set those two values to indicate the time-frame that you want to know.

Here is the sample response from it.

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2017-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2017-02-09T17:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "users_calendar_id": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2017-02-09T14:00:00+08:00",
     "end": "2017-02-09T14:25:00+08:00"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

meaning of the response is the user is busy from 2PM upto 2:25PM.